# How to limit event tracking to single domain in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

When I'm looking at the Google Analytics Events with hostname as second dimension, I can see my local domain plus my test domain mixed up with the data from my real production domain.

Is there a way to tell google analytics to ignore and not record events from any other domain except my real production domain?

I tried creating a View Filter to include only results from my real domain but that does not have any effect on events.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is your filter set up ? A hostname filter should work with events (certainly does for me), so this is quite puzzling.

Comment: Use Ip filter ... It must do the work + It will not override the data, so if you place the filter afterwards you will still see the past data